# Setting field type when outputting CSV from table to table using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, csv

I'm using `arcpy.TableToTable_conversion()` to convert a shapefile to CSV.  In the shapefile, there is a field representing block group FIPS code as a string:

```
550791007004003
```

But it's getting output to the CSV something like:

```
5.50791E+14
```

How can I get the CSV to just read the actual string of numbers?

Have already tried change field width using `feature to feature` , thinking a shorter field width would help.  But no luck.  I do not wish to manually change this field to "text" within the actual CSV.

Comment: Make changes inside schema.ini in the same directory as csv.

Comment: can you elaborate?  I don't understand.

Comment: Can you see schema.ini in this folder? If not, forget about it. I modify schema.ini when go from csv to table to avoid situation you described.

Comment: Large numerics will show as scientific notation if you don't prevent it.

Comment: I do have a schema file.  But I would like to modify it in the script itself. What arcpy method can I use to modify the schema file?

Comment: Vince - suggestions for how to prevent it using arcpy?  They don't make it easy...

Comment: I only trust Python to make text files in the format I need (or, for that matter, read text files with the types I require), so I just use DA cursors to interact with CSV. For me, a "table" is file geodatabase or PostgreSQL, not a CSV, and I'd quote numeric strings to prevent confusion.

Comment: Have a good look on text inside ini file. It's simple: csv file name, followed by fiel name and their type. Overwrite ini file inside your script.

Comment: This work csv->table, not sure it will work other way around.

Comment: What product (ArcGIS Desktop/ArcMap, ArcGIS Pro) and version are you using?  What specific arguments are you passing, especially `field_mapping`?  I just tested [Table To Table (Conversion) - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/tool-reference/conversion/table-to-table.htm) on Pro 2.9.3 and the text number is being outputted without exponential notation.